# Laravel: Using logical operator when setting data type

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a friend's Laravel project and in one of the controllers, he has:
`'force_enabled' => (bool) setting('init_id')` however, I need to make it an `or` statement.

Would this work:
`'force_enabled' => (bool) setting('init_id') || setting('init_name')` ?  Or does (bool) have to be in front of the 2nd setting as well?

Answer (score 1):

Casting as a `bool` should not be required. It depends on the data being returned.

[This link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) explains what values are converted to `false`. All others would convert to `true` automatically.